# Python list is empty which shouldn't be empty

Tags: python, list, tweepy

I am replicating the examples here: https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/intro-to-apis/twitter-data-in-python/

Everything runs smoothly. Only, I want to apply the command for lists in the example.

```
test = [tweet.text for tweet in tweets]
```

But it essentially returns an empty list: print(test).

**EDIT:**

MWE:

```
import sys
sys.modules[__name__].__dict__.clear()

import os
import tweepy as tw
import pandas as pd

consumer_key = 'xxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxx'
access_token = 'xxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxx'


auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)




# Define the search term and the date_since date as variables
search_words = "#wildfire"
date_since = "2020-01-09"

#Collect tweets

tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
    q=search_words,
    lang = "ger",
    since=date_since).items(5)




new_search = search_words + " -filter:retweets"
#new_search


tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
                       q=new_search,
                       lang="en",
                       since=date_since).items(5)

for tweet in tweets:
       print(tweet.text)
test = [tweet.text for tweet in tweets]
print(test)
```

A few comments suggested that tweets could be empty. If I am not mistaken, tweeps is not empty since I can loop over the content.

I guess it is an easy one, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: That list is empty if and only if `tweets` is empty.

Comment: In your code, `tweets` must be empty, therefore `test` also ends up empty.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the full code

Comment: I don't know what kind of thing `Cursor.items` returns, but it's quite possible that it is empty, or that it is something that can be iterated only once (you are attempting to iterate it twice).

Comment: Indeed, it can be iterated over once only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Cursor.items` returns an iterator](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/cursor.py). You iterate it here:

```
for tweet in tweets:
   print(tweet.text)
```

leaving it exhausted. Then you try and iterate it again

```
test = [tweet.text for tweet in tweets]
```

but it has no items left.

Make the list *first*, and then you've got your data in a form you can iterate as many times as you like.

```
test = [tweet.text for tweet in tweets]
for text in test:
    print(text)
```